# Can't add attributes to element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, markup

I've CMS, which renders a markup in such a way where I can't add any additional `id`, `class` or `events` to elements.

In such a way I have to add them programmatically. The task is simple:

1). Find element by class name and add to its successor,(`img`) `id` name

2). add `onClick` attribute to it

3). execute script `onClick` (should swap the image and href's name (*max 3 images*))

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s36phek1/)

Here is a piece of markup:

```
<div class="single-image text-center to_change_inner">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="single-image-container">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a id="btn-1559300726188">Click</a>
</div>
```

**And here is a JQuery**:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    element1 = $('.to_change_inner').children('img'); //find() also doesn't work
    element1.id="imgClickAndChange";
    if (element1.addEventListener) { 
      element1.addEventListener("click", changeImage, false);
    } else {
      if (element1.attachEvent) {  
        element1.attachEvent("click", changeImage);
      }
    }
 });    

 function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://picsum.photos/200/300") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://picsum.photos/20/30";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('btn-1559300726188').setAttribute("onclick", "imgClickAndChange(); return true;");
});
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway, why not use its event handling API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery objects are not DOM elements, they're **sets** of DOM elements.

- To set an attribute on all elements in the set, use [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/): `element1.attr("id", "imgClickAndChange")`
- To set a property, use [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/): `element1.prop("id", "imgClickAndChange")` (`id` happens to be the property reflecting the `id` attribute; `src` is also both an attribute and a reflected property).
- To add an event handler, use [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/): `element1.on("click", changeImage)`.

In general, *setter* methods in jQuery set them on all elements in the set, and *getter* methods get from the *first* element in the set (but there are exceptions).

If for any reason you need to directly access the DOM element(s) in the set, you can do that with brackets notation like with an array.

More in [the API docs](https://api.jquery.com/) and [the learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/).

---

According to your HTML, you have an error here:

> ```
> element1 = $('.to_change_inner').children('img'); //find() also doesn't work
> ```

The comment is incorrect, `find` would be what you want there, not `children`:

```js
var element1 = $('.to_change_inner').children('img'); // Doesn't work
console.log(element1.length); // 0, no matching elements

var element1 = $('.to_change_inner').find('img'); // Works
console.log(element1.length); // 1, there was a matching element
```

```html
<div class="single-image text-center to_change_inner">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="single-image-container">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That code also seems to be falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), you need to declare `element1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    element1 = $('.to_change_inner img');
    element1.attr('id',"imgClickAndChange");

    element1.on('click',function(){changeImage();})
 });    

 function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "https://picsum.photos/200/300") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://picsum.photos/20/30";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('btn-1559300726188').setAttribute("onclick", "imgClickAndChange(); return true;");
});
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. What did you change? *Why* did you change it? Where can the OP learn more?